# Rails is looking for /config/config/database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, path

I'm trying to migrate a Rails 2.3.4 application to Rails 3.1.1, and when i try to reach my root_path, i get a 500 errors.

In my Nginx's log, i get this :

> [ pid=12653 thr=2225406380 file=utils.rb:176 time=2011-11-14 14:39:42.907 ]: *** Exception Errno::ENOENT in application (No such file or directory - /Users/cedric/Code/my-app/config/config/database.yml) (process 12653, thread #):

It seems that Rails is looking for my database.yml in `config/config` path instead of `config/`.

Does anyone know how i can fix this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If your situation was like mine, you probably have an extra config.ru nested inside the config/ directory. Therefore:

```
rm config/config.ru
```

This should clear up your problem.

When upgrading, make sure to generate a bare rails3 app and closely compare its structure to catch errors like this.